# How to use FormControl with p-calendar and override placeholder

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

[Here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) is a list of Form controls I was going through:

I have two modes (radio button) True and False. Both are applicable to one `p-calendar`:

```
<p-calendar
  [formControl]="startFormControl"
  [(ngModel)]="startValue"
  placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY">
</p-calendar>
```

If mode is false the filed is non-editable i.e. read only. But when mode is changed to true, the same calendar should be editable. This much I'm able to do. But my placeholder is not being replaced by actual date. Here is my logic:

```
startDatePlaceholder= new Date();
startValue;

ngOnChanges() {
    console.log("changed detected");
    this.startValue=this.startDatePlaceholder;
    this.startFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        this.startValue = value ;
        console.log("changed value ", value); // Output: NULL
    });
}
```

The problem is that value is not being changed that is why it is throwing `null`. Please suggest something here.

P.S: Actual code is way too complex to re-create on stackblitz or plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I anticipate that, your main problem is your are unable to detect the change of the value of `p-calendar`. If your code below=>

```
this.firstName.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
         console.log('name has changed:', value)
       });
```

is not working then you can try `ngModelChange`. Here is my solution given below for both `ngModelChange` and `valueChanges.subscribe`=>

**HTML**

```
 <form [formGroup]="formGroup" >
    <p-calendar [formControl]="firstName"
      [(ngModel)]="startValue"
      (ngModelChange)="datachanged($event)"
      placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY">
    </p-calendar>
    </form>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent {

    formGroup: FormGroup;
    firstName = new FormControl();
    constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        
      this.firstName.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
         console.log('name has changed:', value)
       });  
    }
   
  datachanged($event) {
    console.log("changed detected:"+$event);
  }

}
```

**NOTE:** Demo link [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-cfjspw-4p8thc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Please check the link and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated the scenario at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-calendar-sxpzuz?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

You can simply enable/disable the calendar on the `change` event of your radio buttons.

And you can see I've logged the date into the console at your mode (radio button selection) change. The date doesn't become null at any point.

So, you don't need to work with the placeholder.